# Teamspeak 3 Database Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, sqlite

I am working on a project for a 'redudant' teamspeak server wtih aws. Ive got most of what I need done, however I'm running into a snag.

Teamspeak A is the primary server, and is running fine. I need to copy the database from server A to server B.

I'm doing this via S3 and a the aws CLI. Great,

On server two, I replace the ts3server_sqlitedb file with the one from server A, and i get the following message :

```
2018-03-31 03:07:40.763169|CRITICAL|ServerLibPriv |   |Server() DatabaseError file is encrypted or is not a databaseTeamSpeak 3 server started, for details please view the log file
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

My issue was i was using the sqlite .dump command, and that was changing the format of the file!